# Unable to add doctype tag to xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd

I seek your help, I have an automatically generated XML File that I need to validate against a DTD, so I have to modify the generated XML to add the doctype tag isn't added when I use the following code, I have consulted many threads but no positive result.

Here is the concerned part in my code:

```
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(extractedFileURL);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
///Add Doctype declaration to the extracted XML File
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation domImpl = doc.getImplementation();
DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("doctype",
    "SYSTEM"
        ,
    "registry\\ixb\\dtds\\extractor.dtd\\generatedDTD1.dtd");
//transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(extractedFileURL));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of your input, and what you expect as an output? Thank you.

Comment: It works for me.  What does your file look like after that code executes?

Comment: it doesn't change, i have changed the strategy now i read the XML as a String and insert the doctype tag in it